# Наиболее рациональная структура таблицы графика работы

Tags: sql, postgresql, структуры-данных

Есть мастера, для которых нужно проставить их рабочие часы соответственно дням недели. Учитывая, что мастер может работать когда хочет, например час через два. А также у них же могут быть исключения на конкретные даты. Я решил сделать так. Таблица: timetable с полями id, master_id, time_from, time_to, weekdays, datetime.

Итого в time_from и time_to - указываем промежутки работы мастера допустим 11:00 до 13:00, в weekdays пишем перечисления дней недели по которым данный промежуток действует (Есть альтернатива сделать 7 bool полей вместо этого, будет ли это лучше? В первом случаи нужно будет в запросах использовать LIKE %%, а в этом случаи будет много полей). Также можно на эти же дни недели указать другие промежутки, допустим чловек пообедал в 13.00 и снова за работу: добавляется ещё запись с 14:00 до 18:00 с тем же полем weekdays. А если человек захотел сделать какое то другое расписание допустим на 23 февраля, то он указывает промежутки и weekdays при этом равен NULL, а datetime дате 23го февраля.

Итак вопросы:
1. Правильно ли вообще спроектирована таблица? Может надо несколько таблиц, может есть более умное решение для хранения очень гибкого графика работ.
2. Если всё-таки такой способ нормален, то как лучше хранить поле weekdays, в каком типе данных, или может за место него лучше 7 bool полей?
3. Как лучше хранить промежутки времени "с 14:00 до 18:00"

**UPD 1:**
1. Таблица графика работы нужна только для того, чтобы пользователям отображать текущую занятость мастера, чтобы пользователь смог записаться на свободное время.
2. А вот этот тип bit я совсем не понимаю, битовые маски эти. Просто как в таких хранить пн, вт, вс например? Как потом в запросе проверять работает ли он в воскресение?
3. Да, меня самого смущает такое хранение, как бы вы предложили? Может быть в минутах? Типа 14 часов это 14*60 цифра будет хранится.

Answer (score 1):

1. Возможно я чего-то не понимаю, но не кажется ли вам, что у вас имеются периодические и разовые события. Причем периодические события, могут иметь начало, могут иметь начало и конец? Что происходит, если мастер работает с 30 февраля текущего года в течение следующих 5 лет по понедельникам? Будете генерировать записи? А если он потом уволится через 3 года, стирать оставшиеся 2 года? Может стоит предусмотреть два типа событий - периодический и разовый?
2. Только через запятую не храните, можно вообще использовать целое число smallint и упаковать в него при помощи поразрядных операторов, есть тип bit, можно задействовать тип array.
3. Как вы при таком подходе будете хранить интервал с 14 до 00 часов следующего дня? 14:00 - 23:59? Тогда и другие часы нужно будет хранить так.

Прошу прощение за вопросы в ответе, вы просто ближе к данным, вам виднее какие операции с ними потом будут осуществляться. База расписания - всегда интересная и не однозначная задача.

Comment: Спасибо)  Ответил апдейтом)